# How to resample numpy array with max length of index in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, resampling

I'm a newbie in python and trying to normalize each index in list using `preprocessing.normalize`. However, it gives me an error with `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

And then, I found what the problem was. It was because the `length(size)` of each index in `np.array` was different.

Here is my code,

```
result = []

for url in target_url :
    sensor = pd.read_csv(url, header=None, delimiter=r"\s+")
    result.append(sensor[2])

result = np.array(result)
# I want to resample here before it goes to normalize.
result = preprocessing.normalize(result, norm='l1')
```

I have `target_url` to get sensor data from webserver, and each appends to the `result` list. Then, it converts to array by using `np.array`

For example,

I have `len(result[0])` has `121598` and `len(result[1])` has `1215601`. I want to make `result[0]` to be same length of `result[1]` using resample to fill NaN.

How can I do that?

Please help me out here.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

After normalizing, I'm trying to do correlation using `corr()`

Here is the code,

```
result = preprocessing.normalize(result, norm='l1')
ret = pd.DataFrame(result)
corMat = DataFrame(ret.T.corr())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `pandas` to read csv, you are off to a good start. One way to do it is simply use `pd.concat`, to join the Series (I assume `sensor[2]` is a Series) in the `result` list into one `DataFrame`. This is an example:

```
a = [pd.Series([1, 2, 3]), pd.Series([1, 2]), pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4])]
pd.concat(a, axis=1)
```

Which gives:

```
     0    1  2
0  1.0  1.0  1
1  2.0  2.0  2
2  3.0  NaN  3
3  NaN  NaN  4
```

In the example provided by OP, this should suffice:

```
result = []

for url in target_url :
    sensor = pd.read_csv(url, header=None, delimiter=r"\s+")
    result.append(sensor[2])

# concatenate Series, and do both forward and backward fill for NaNs 
result = pd.concat(result, axis=1).fillna(method='bfill').fillna(method='ffill')

result = preprocessing.normalize(result, norm='l1')

# correlation
pd.DataFrame(result).T.corr()
```

Depending on what the Series indices look like, and your application, you can do different types of concatenations. Here's the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :) I'm actually trying to do correlation after normalizing. And I want to fill that NaN with bfill or ffill using resample. :'(
Let me edit my question. :)

Comment: Why not just use `fillna(method='bfill')?`

Comment: Thanks for the comment and answer.. I have one quick question. After putting the code, it gives me like `Error: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'corr'`

Comment: Oh sorry my bad. You should cast to `DataFrame` to use `pandas's` `cov` or just use `np.cov(result)`. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! :) it gives me an error but I figured out with using `result_temp = [result.iloc[:,i].tolist() for i in range(0, lenghofColumn)]` and then do correlation! :)

Comment: Thanks for supporting again! :)